# Most efficient collection for filtering a Java Stream?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm storing several `Thing`s in a Collection. The individual `Thing`s are unique, but their types aren't. The order in which they are stored also doesn't matter.

I want to use Java 8's Stream API to search it for a specific type with this code:

```
Collection<Thing> things = ...;
// ... populate things ...
Stream<Thing> filtered = things.stream.filter(thing -> thing.type.equals(searchType));
```

Is there a particular `Collection` that would make the `filter()` more efficient?

I'm inclined to think no, because the filter has to iterate through the entire collection.

On the other hand, if the collection is some sort of tree that is indexed by the `Thing.type` then the `filter()` might be able to take advantage of that fact. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you use a `Map<Type, List<Thing>>` instead?

Comment: @Keppil Yes thank you. After consideration I think that what you propose is the most efficient. Someone else just deleted a comment that said that the collection I'm looking for would require some knowledge of the internals of `Thing` so would be better to index `Thing.type` through a Map.

Answer (score 2):

The stream operations like filter are not that specialized to take an advantage in special cases. For example, `IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000_000).filter(x -> x > 999_999_000)` will actually iterate all the input numbers, it cannot just "skip" the first 999_999_000. So your question is reduced to find the collection with the most efficient iteration.

The iteration is usually performed in `Spliterator.forEachRemaining` method (for non-short-circuiting stream) and in `Spliterator.tryAdvance` method (for short-circuiting stream), so you can take a look into the corresponding spliterator implementation and check how efficient it is. To my opinion the most efficient is an array (either bare or wrapped into list with `Arrays.asList`): it has minimal overhead. `ArrayList` is also quite fast, but for short-circuiting operation it will check the `modCount` (to detect concurrent modification) on every iteration which would add very slight overhead. Other types like `HashSet` or `LinkedList` are comparably slower, though in most of applications this difference is practically insignificant.

Note that parallel streams should be used with care. For example, the splitting of `LinkedList` is quite poor and you may experience worse performance than in sequential case.

Comment: Sorry if the sentence was misunderstood (English not being my first language) but I actually meant: ArrayList = good, LinkedList = poor, any Set = poor ;-)

Comment: @mtj, probably I misread your answer. I removed the reference to it, sorry. Actually splitting of `HashSet` or `TreeSet` works quite well (much better than `LinkedList`).

Comment: Regarding sets, you are right that the partitioning is implemented in a very efficient way, but both hash- and treeset have the problem, that the split sizes are not really well predictable. I have seen splits around 60% to 40% in sets, and depending on your concrete data it might get even worse.

Comment: @mtj in general it's not a big problem. After all even with exactly even splitting there's no guarantee that downstream item processing has the same complexity for every item. Stream pipeline usually creates about (number of cores)*4 tasks to mitigate this problem, so if some happen to finish earlier, they can steal pending parts from another cpu core.

Comment: The point is not that the stream operations aren’t specialized, but rather that they can’t be since they can’t look into the `Predicate` to find out what it will do. The `modCount` of an `ArrayList` is nothing to worry about as it’s intentionally not synchronized, so the HotSpot optimizer can move its update out of the loop (effectively eliminating the check, that’s why it is called a “best effort” check, it doesn’t happen when the performance would suffer).

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to understand, regarding this question, is that when you pass a lambda expression to a particular library like the `Stream` API, all the library receives is an implementation of a functional interface, e.g. an instance of `Predicate`. It has no knowledge about what that implementation will do and therefore has no way to exploit scenarios like filtering sorted data via comparison. The stream library simply doesn’t know that the `Predicate` is doing a comparison.

An implementation doing such an optimization would need an interaction of the JVM, which knows and understands the code, and the library, which knows the semantics. Such thing does not happen in current implementation and is currently far away, at least as I can see it.

If the source is a tree or sorted list and you want to benefit from that for filtering, you have to do it using APIs operating on the source, before creating the stream. E.g. suppose, we have a `TreeSet` and want to filter it to get items within a particular range, like

```
// our made-up source
TreeSet<Integer> tree=IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
// the naive implementation
tree.stream().filter(i -> i>=65 && i<91).forEach(i->System.out.print((char)i.intValue()));
```

We can do instead:

```
tree.tailSet(65).headSet(91).stream().forEach(i->System.out.print((char)i.intValue()));
```

which will utilize the sorted/tree nature. When we have a sorted list instead, say

```
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>(tree);
```

utilizing the sorted nature is more complex as the collection itself doesn’t know that it’s sorted and doesn’t offer operations utilizing that directly:

```
int ix=Collections.binarySearch(list, 65);
if(ix<0) ix=~ix;
if(ix>0) list=list.subList(ix, list.size());
ix=Collections.binarySearch(list, 91);
if(ix<0) ix=~ix;
if(ix<list.size()) list=list.subList(0, ix);
list.stream().forEach(i->System.out.print((char)i.intValue()));
```

Of course, the stream operations here are only exemplary and you don’t need a stream at all, when all you do then is `forEach`…

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there's no such differenciation for normal streaming.

However, you might be better off when you use parallel streaming when you use a collection which is easily devideable, like ArrayList over LinkedList or any type of Set.